# Python sorting 2D list by multiple colums not provided expected results

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have a set of data with 9 columns, that i want to sort by column 9, then 1, then 2

```
list.sort(key=itemgetter(8,0,1), reverse=False)
```

I dont know how to add an attachment here, but my sorted list ends up looking like this, and as you can see, it is sorted by column 9 (which is all zeros at first), then column 1, and then for column 2, particular at lines 9-17, it makes no sense:

```
   -5.8000    -4.0000     0.1005    -3.4900    -2.5000          0          1          2          0

   -5.8000     4.9500     0.1005    -3.4900    -2.5000          0          1          2          0

   -5.5000    -3.6250     0.2500    -5.5700    -5.4700          1          1          2          0

   -5.5000     4.5750     0.2500    -5.5700    -5.4700          1          1          2          0

   -5.1600    -0.3750     0.1105    -2.2850    -2.0000          1          1          1          0

   -5.1600    -0.3750     0.1105    -6.0700    -5.7850          1          1          3          0

   -5.1600    -0.3750     0.1725    -5.7850    -5.5700          1          1          3          0

   -5.1600    -0.3750     0.1002    -6.6102    -6.0702          0          1          4          0

   -5.1000    -0.9500     0.2425    -2.5000    -2.0000          1          1          1          0

   -5.1000    -0.9500     0.2425    -6.0700    -5.5700          1          1          3          0

   -5.1000     1.1000     0.2425    -2.5000    -2.0000          1          1          1          0

   -5.1000     1.1000     0.2425    -6.0700    -5.5700          1          1          3          0

   -5.1000    -0.9500     0.2590    -1.3750    -0.2500          1          1          0          0

   -5.1000    -0.9500     0.2160    -2.0000    -1.3750          1          1          0          0

   -5.1000     1.1000     0.2590    -1.3750    -0.2500          1          1          0          0

   -5.1000     1.1000     0.2160    -2.0000    -1.3750          1          1          0          0

   -5.1000    -0.9500     0.2425    -5.5700    -2.5000          1          1          2          0
```

any idea whats going on here?

Answer (score 0):

turns out, i just needed to round the input data before sorting it. There must have been differences on the order of 1E-6